# use bitlocker without admin privilege in windows7

Tags: uac, bitlocker

i have some problem with windows 7 on locked drive by bitlocker  when i join a domain.

in windows 7 when i try to unlock encrypted drive after join a domain the bitlocker ask me UAC privilege to administrator Whereas on windows 10 with the same Conditions have no problem and no privilege

in my organization some people use bitlocker and i can not set all of them into administrator

please help me find one way to add people with limited account on domain and ability to use their bitlocker without administrator privilege

Comment: Just give the User group the required permission.  Bitlocker does not required being an Administrator in Windows 7.  If you are getting a UAC prompt on Windows 7 your group policy is likely to blame.

Comment: it is not working. i member it to administrator domain but not work. only member of local admin can use bitlocker. but in windows 10 there are no problem such that

Comment: You will have to determine what permission is required, that your users don't have, you don't have place them in the Administrator user group to achieve that.  Out of interested, what version of Windows 7, are we even talking about?

Comment: i was forced temporarily join users to local admin. my problem appear on windows7 ultimate and on windows 10 every things is ok

https://s32.postimg.org/mlditdi0l/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Are you sure the drive's ACL allows for Users to access it?  I don't doubt you had to move the users into the user group, I am just saying, you can simply give the `User` user group the required permission instead.

Comment: yes i give full permission to target user in derive's ACL
.i try every simple and complex permission.
if it possible for you try it on own windows